# Consul deregister 'failing' services

Tags: microservices, mesos, mesosphere, consul, consul-template

I have consul running on Consul v0.5.2 version & services running in Mesos. Services keep moving from 1 server to another.

Is there way to deregister services in consul that are in 'failing' state? I am able to get the list of services in failing state using this curl

```
curl http://localhost:8500/v1/health/state/critical
```

Issue that we are seeing is over a period of time in consul UI we have stale data & making the whole UI unusable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consul by default do not deregister unhealthy services instead marks them as critical.
From Consul 0.7 there is special option (`deregister_critical_service_after`) that allows you to define time after unhealthy service will be deregstered

From Consul [0.7 Changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/v0.7.0/CHANGELOG.md)

> **Automatic Service Deregistration:** Added a new
> [`deregister_critical_service_after`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/check#deregistercriticalserviceafter) timeout field for health checks
> which will cause the service associated with that check to get
> deregistered if the check is critical for longer than the timeout.
> This is useful for cleanup of health checks registered natively by
> applications, or in other situations where services may not always be
> cleanly shutdown. [GH-679](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/679)

If you are usign Marathon then you can consider using [allegro/marathon-consul](https://github.com/allegro/marathon-consul) it will deregister task when its dead

Comment: How to specify the `deregister_critical_service_after` value in  consul? I did not know how to use it. @janisz the document did not mention how to use it.

Comment: https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/check#deregistercriticalserviceafter

Comment: I configure it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007497/how-to-deregister-the-service-in-consul-when-using-spring-could-consul still did not work. @janisz

Answer (score 0):

Along with what janisz said, you can also run your services in Nomad and Nomad will automatically register and deregister your services for you.  See the [Nomad Service Discovery](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/service-discovery/index.html) docs for additional details.