# Remove dead services from Consul

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-consul

We have a number of Spring Boot applications that register themselves with Consul (via Spring Cloud Consul). If I stop those applications via `docker-compose stop myservice` then they de-register themselves correctly and disappear from Consul.

If I use `docker-compose kill myservice` then the deregistration doesn't happen. I understand that on a UNIX system it's impossible to catch the SIGKILL event, so there's no way to force the de-registration.

What we're therefore seeing is services in Consul that never removed (marked as `critical` but still visible in the UI). Is there a way to force Consul to refresh what's registered, so that the dead services are removed?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consul deregister 'failing' services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010594/consul-deregister-failing-services)

Answer (score 9):

It seems, that you have to use Consul HTTP API and manually deregister unavailable services. API gives you 2 different ways to deregister some service, the first one via [agent endpoint](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/agent.html#agent_service_deregister) like so

```
curl -v -X PUT http://%CONSUL_IP%:8500/v1/agent/service/deregister/<ServiceID>
```

and the second via [catalog](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/catalog.html). Unfortunately  in both cases you have to make http-request manually.

Comment: Is there a better solution for this? Right now we are also having same issue and we are manually `deregistering` the orphaned or dead consul services using the Consul HTTP API.