# how to deregister the service in consul when using spring cloud consul

Tags: java, consul

I am using consul(`docker.io/bitnami/consul:1.10.2-debian-10-r0`) as my register center, first I add the spring consul dependencies(`2.2.7.RELEASE`) using gradle:

```
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery"
```

then add configuration in `application.properties` of my project:

```
# registry center
spring.cloud.consul.host=consul-1630121482-headless.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local
spring.cloud.consule.port=8500
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-interval=15s
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.instance-id= ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.prefer-ip-address= true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.deregister=false
# service check failed, delete service
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-critical-timeout=10m
```

the register could registry success and works fine. But now I facing a problem that the legacy service did not remove automatic. I have already add the deregister config, why did not work? why the service still did not deregistered automatic? ` this is my kubernetes yaml config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: consul-1630121482
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
  uid: 2c00fca9-6d80-42a2-9bb9-9f80e1ed3cbe
  resourceVersion: '4946609'
  generation: 4
  creationTimestamp: '2021-08-28T03:31:27Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: consul-1630121482
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: consul
    helm.sh/chart: consul-9.3.5
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"annotations":{"meta.helm.sh/release-name":"consul-1630121482","meta.helm.sh/release-namespace":"reddwarf-pro"},"creationTimestamp":"2021-08-28T03:31:27Z","generation":3,"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"consul-1630121482","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"consul","helm.sh/chart":"consul-9.3.5"},"managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{".":{},"f:meta.helm.sh/release-name":{},"f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace":{}},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/instance":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/name":{},"f:helm.sh/chart":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:podManagementPolicy":{},"f:replicas":{},"f:revisionHistoryLimit":{},"f:selector":{},"f:serviceName":{},"f:template":{"f:metadata":{"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/instance":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/name":{},"f:helm.sh/chart":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:affinity":{".":{},"f:podAntiAffinity":{".":{},"f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":{}}},"f:containers":{"k:{\"name\":\"consul\"}":{".":{},"f:env":{".":{},"k:{\"name\":\"BITNAMI_DEBUG\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_BOOTSTRAP_EXPECT\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_DATACENTER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_DISABLE_KEYRING_FILE\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_DNS_PORT_NUMBER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_DOMAIN\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_NODE_NAME\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:valueFrom":{".":{},"f:fieldRef":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:fieldPath":{}}}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_RAFT_MULTIPLIER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_RETRY_JOIN\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_RPC_PORT_NUMBER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_SERF_LAN_PORT_NUMBER\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{}},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSUL_UI\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}}},"f:image":{},"f:imagePullPolicy":{},"f:lifecycle":{".":{},"f:preStop":{".":{},"f:exec":{".":{},"f:command":{}}}},"f:livenessProbe":{".":{},"f:exec":{".":{},"f:command":{}},"f:failureThreshold":{},"f:initialDelaySeconds":{},"f:periodSeconds":{},"f:successThreshold":{},"f:timeoutSeconds":{}},"f:name":{},"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"containerPort\":8300,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":8301,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":8301,\"protocol\":\"UDP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":8400,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":8500,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":8600,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":8600,\"protocol\":\"UDP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}}},"f:readinessProbe":{".":{},"f:exec":{".":{},"f:command":{}},"f:failureThreshold":{},"f:initialDelaySeconds":{},"f:periodSeconds":{},"f:successThreshold":{},"f:timeoutSeconds":{}},"f:resources":{},"f:securityContext":{".":{},"f:runAsUser":{}},"f:terminationMessagePath":{},"f:terminationMessagePolicy":{},"f:volumeMounts":{".":{},"k:{\"mountPath\":\"/bitnami/consul\"}":{".":{},"f:mountPath":{},"f:name":{}}}}},"f:dnsPolicy":{},"f:restartPolicy":{},"f:schedulerName":{},"f:securityContext":{".":{},"f:fsGroup":{}},"f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds":{}}},"f:updateStrategy":{"f:type":{}},"f:volumeClaimTemplates":{}}},"manager":"Go-http-client","operation":"Update","time":"2021-08-28T03:31:27Z"},{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:status":{"f:collisionCount":{},"f:currentReplicas":{},"f:currentRevision":{},"f:observedGeneration":{},"f:readyReplicas":{},"f:replicas":{},"f:updateRevision":{},"f:updatedReplicas":{}}},"manager":"kube-controller-manager","operation":"Update","time":"2021-08-29T11:46:21Z"}],"name":"consul-1630121482","namespace":"reddwarf-pro","selfLink":"/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/reddwarf-pro/statefulsets/consul-1630121482","uid":"2c00fca9-6d80-42a2-9bb9-9f80e1ed3cbe"},"spec":{"podManagementPolicy":"Parallel","replicas":3,"revisionHistoryLimit":10,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"consul-1630121482","app.kubernetes.io/name":"consul"}},"serviceName":"consul-1630121482-headless","template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"consul-1630121482","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"consul","helm.sh/chart":"consul-9.3.5"}},"spec":{"affinity":{"podAntiAffinity":{"preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":[{"podAffinityTerm":{"labelSelector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"consul-1630121482","app.kubernetes.io/name":"consul"}},"namespaces":["reddwarf-pro"],"topologyKey":"kubernetes.io/hostname"},"weight":1}]}},"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"BITNAMI_DEBUG","value":"false"},{"name":"CONSUL_NODE_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"apiVersion":"v1","fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}},{"name":"CONSUL_RETRY_JOIN","value":"consul-1630121482-headless.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local"},{"name":"CONSUL_DISABLE_KEYRING_FILE","value":"true"},{"name":"CONSUL_BOOTSTRAP_EXPECT","value":"3"},{"name":"CONSUL_RAFT_MULTIPLIER","value":"1"},{"name":"CONSUL_DOMAIN","value":"consul"},{"name":"CONSUL_DATACENTER","value":"dc1"},{"name":"CONSUL_UI","value":"true"},{"name":"CONSUL_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER","value":"8500"},{"name":"CONSUL_DNS_PORT_NUMBER"},{"name":"CONSUL_RPC_PORT_NUMBER"},{"name":"CONSUL_SERF_LAN_PORT_NUMBER"}],"image":"docker.io/bitnami/consul:1.10.2-debian-10-r0","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","lifecycle":{"preStop":{"exec":{"command":["consul","leave"]}}},"livenessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["consul","operator","raft","list-peers"]},"failureThreshold":6,"initialDelaySeconds":50,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":5},"name":"consul","ports":[{"containerPort":8500,"name":"http","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":8400,"name":"rpc","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":8301,"name":"serflan-tcp","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":8301,"name":"serflan-udp","protocol":"UDP"},{"containerPort":8300,"name":"rpc-server","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":8600,"name":"dns-tcp","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":8600,"name":"dns-udp","protocol":"UDP"}],"readinessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["consul","members"]},"failureThreshold":6,"initialDelaySeconds":25,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":5},"resources":{},"securityContext":{"runAsUser":1001},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/bitnami/consul","name":"data"}]}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","restartPolicy":"Always","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{"fsGroup":1001},"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30}},"updateStrategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"},"volumeClaimTemplates":[{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"data"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"8Gi"}},"volumeMode":"Filesystem"},"status":{"phase":"Pending"}}]}}
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: consul-1630121482
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: reddwarf-pro
  managedFields:
    - manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-08-28T03:31:27Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-name': {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:podManagementPolicy': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:revisionHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:selector': {}
          'f:serviceName': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:labels':
                .: {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
                'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:affinity':
                .: {}
                'f:podAntiAffinity':
                  .: {}
                  'f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution': {}
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"consul"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:env':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"name":"BITNAMI_DEBUG"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_BOOTSTRAP_EXPECT"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_DATACENTER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_DISABLE_KEYRING_FILE"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_DNS_PORT_NUMBER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_DOMAIN"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_NODE_NAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:fieldRef':
                          .: {}
                          'f:apiVersion': {}
                          'f:fieldPath': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_RAFT_MULTIPLIER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_RETRY_JOIN"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_RPC_PORT_NUMBER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_SERF_LAN_PORT_NUMBER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONSUL_UI"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                  'f:image': {}
                  'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                  'f:lifecycle':
                    .: {}
                    'f:preStop':
                      .: {}
                      'f:exec':
                        .: {}
                        'f:command': {}
                  'f:livenessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:exec':
                      .: {}
                      'f:command': {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:ports':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8300,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8301,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8301,"protocol":"UDP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8400,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8500,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8600,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8600,"protocol":"UDP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                  'f:readinessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:exec':
                      .: {}
                      'f:command': {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:resources': {}
                  'f:securityContext':
                    .: {}
                    'f:runAsUser': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
                  'f:volumeMounts':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"mountPath":"/bitnami/consul"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:mountPath': {}
                      'f:name': {}
              'f:dnsPolicy': {}
              'f:restartPolicy': {}
              'f:schedulerName': {}
              'f:securityContext':
                .: {}
                'f:fsGroup': {}
              'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
          'f:updateStrategy':
            'f:type': {}
          'f:volumeClaimTemplates': {}
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-08-29T11:48:47Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            'f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:template':
            'f:spec':
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"consul"}':
                  'f:livenessProbe':
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                  'f:readinessProbe':
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2021-08-29T11:51:17Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:collisionCount': {}
          'f:currentReplicas': {}
          'f:currentRevision': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:readyReplicas': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:updateRevision': {}
          'f:updatedReplicas': {}
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/reddwarf-pro/statefulsets/consul-1630121482
status:
  observedGeneration: 4
  replicas: 3
  readyReplicas: 3
  currentReplicas: 3
  updatedReplicas: 3
  currentRevision: consul-1630121482-69bbcb9d47
  updateRevision: consul-1630121482-69bbcb9d47
  collisionCount: 0
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: consul-1630121482
      app.kubernetes.io/name: consul
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: consul-1630121482
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: consul
        helm.sh/chart: consul-9.3.5
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: consul
          image: 'docker.io/bitnami/consul:1.10.2-debian-10-r0'
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8500
              protocol: TCP
            - name: rpc
              containerPort: 8400
              protocol: TCP
            - name: serflan-tcp
              containerPort: 8301
              protocol: TCP
            - name: serflan-udp
              containerPort: 8301
              protocol: UDP
            - name: rpc-server
              containerPort: 8300
              protocol: TCP
            - name: dns-tcp
              containerPort: 8600
              protocol: TCP
            - name: dns-udp
              containerPort: 8600
              protocol: UDP
          env:
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: 'false'
            - name: CONSUL_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: CONSUL_RETRY_JOIN
              value: consul-1630121482-headless.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local
            - name: CONSUL_DISABLE_KEYRING_FILE
              value: 'true'
            - name: CONSUL_BOOTSTRAP_EXPECT
              value: '3'
            - name: CONSUL_RAFT_MULTIPLIER
              value: '1'
            - name: CONSUL_DOMAIN
              value: consul
            - name: CONSUL_DATACENTER
              value: dc1
            - name: CONSUL_UI
              value: 'true'
            - name: CONSUL_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER
              value: '8500'
            - name: CONSUL_DNS_PORT_NUMBER
            - name: CONSUL_RPC_PORT_NUMBER
            - name: CONSUL_SERF_LAN_PORT_NUMBER
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /bitnami/consul
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - consul
                - operator
                - raft
                - list-peers
            initialDelaySeconds: 50
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - consul
                - members
            initialDelaySeconds: 25
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - consul
                  - leave
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1001
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: consul-1630121482
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: consul
                namespaces:
                  - reddwarf-pro
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: data
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 8Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
      status:
        phase: Pending
  serviceName: consul-1630121482-headless
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```

I have already tried to add config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: dolphin-gateway
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        health-check-interval: 15s
        deregister: true
        health-check-critical-timeout: 5s
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
        prefer-ip-address: true
      enabled: true
      host: consul-1630121482-headless.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local
```

this is the consul dashboard ui: https://consul.poemhub.top/ui/dc1/services/dolphin-gateway/instances. This is the invalid service:

[image]

Comment: What version of Consul do you have?

Comment: I have added the version info @janisz

Answer (score 1):

```
These worked for me.

    spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.register=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.deregister=false
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-path=/context-path/actuator/health
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-interval=3s
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-timeout=3s
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-critical-timeout=5s
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.scheme=http
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-tls-skip-verify=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.prefer-ip-address=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.register-health-check=true
spring.cloud.consul.port=8500
spring.cloud.consul.host=consul-headless

Apply these in application.properties file.
```

Comment: Please add an example & explain it. Where we can configure these properties given in answer. Pls elaborate

Comment: @DineshDontha Please discuss, still if you are facing issue.

Comment: I have tried what you said but did not work. @BilalHayat the legacy registered record did not removed.

Comment: @Dolphin What version of spring-boot and spring-cloud version r u using ?